# Why do Heavy-Fermions primarily form in compounds containing f-electrons?

Tags: condensed-matter

I'm trying to understand why the majority of Heavy-Fermions form in materials containing unpaired f-electrons (Ce, Yb, U being the most common), rather than in materials with unpaired d-electrons (In d-electron materials you can still observe an enhanced mass, but typically much smaller than that observed for f-electrons).

I realize that the underlying physics involve the RKKY interaction, Kondo effect, and Kondo lattice, though each of these can also occur in d-electron materials. There must be something causing a stronger interaction between the f-electrons and conduction electrons than in the equivalent d-electron systems.

My best guess is that this relates to the localized nature of the f-electron states (4f lies inside 5s and 5p), which can result in some shielding of the f-electrons. Perhaps this weakens the interaction between f-electrons at different lattice sites, while increasing the interaction with conduction electrons.

None of the papers I have read address this issue, so if anyone has a reference that would be ideal.